# Preventing update flicker of a Dashing Widget

Tags: javascript, dashing

I have created a number of widgets for my Dashboard that need to update periodically. When they do this the widget items flicker for a second which I believe will be quite distracting when the dashboard is deployed on a large TV monitor on the wall.

I currently cache what is being sent and compare it to the data fetched on the currented run to ensure the widget is only rerendered when there is a change to the data but as it stands the widget still massively flickers when an update does get put through.

Are there any other techniques to minimise this flickering that I could implement? What are possible causes for the flickering? Is it just the renderer taking it's time with a new set of data?

I'm attempting to use the Coffee script to hide the flicker but am rather unsure of the direction to go in.

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is the browser re-drawing elements each time you send update event from the server. Unfortunately some dashing widgets do not take that into account out of the box. However, I can offer you an example solution for the list widget. Original list widget redraws the complete list every time there's an update from the server side. To avoid this, one needs to create the list elements in advance and update the values inline so that the widget is rendered without any flickering.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/kivancsahici/371b0de9752fafa9f4939926c971acf3) you can check the solution immediately, so basically you should modify the coffeescript code of the widget that flickers